# Out of memory crash with firebase angular

Tags: android, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a ionic app with Angular and Firebase. The code below is working fine when run on a browser. But it always crashes on an Android device (physical or virtual)

```
this.subsGetAllApp = this.afDb.collection<IAppointment>('appointments', (ref) => ref.where(idType, '==', userId)).snapshotChanges().pipe(
    debounceTime(2000),
    map((docs: DocumentChangeAction<IAppointment>[]) => {
        return (docs.map((doc) => {
            return ({
                ...doc.payload.doc.data() as IAppointment,
                id: doc.payload.doc.id
            });
        }));
    })
).subscribe((appointments) => {
    this.store.dispatch(new GetAllAppointment(appointments));
});
```

This code is launched at the app init. I have tried to add more where clauses to the query to fetch less data. It worked which means there is a memory issue somewhere that is only raised at a certain amount of data.

The error log from logcat :

```
2020-08-04 23:25:38.360 6236-6236/com.osteoapp.app E/chromium: [ERROR:aw_browser_terminator.cc(113)] Renderer process (6408) crash detected (code 5).
2020-08-04 23:25:38.379 6236-6236/com.osteoapp.app A/chromium: [FATAL:crashpad_client_linux.cc(404)] Render process (6408)'s crash wasn't handled by all associated  webviews, triggering application crash.
2020-08-04 23:25:38.802 6236-6236/com.osteoapp.app A/libc: Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL), code 2 (ILL_ILLOPN), fault addr 0xd43dfc30 in tid 6236 (om.osteoapp.app), pid 6236 (om.osteoapp.app)
enter code here
```

Comment: Could you please share the error which is giving your when running in Android?

Comment: Do you have android:largeHeap="true" set in your Manifest.xml file?

Comment: I added the stacktrace to the question. I've tried set largeHeap to true with no success. The only thing that works is to actually reduce the amount of data fetched

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because of enough memory for all your data.

Please try to increase the memory. You can do this by modifying the node_modules/.bin/ionic-app-scripts.cmd by adding the following:

```
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe"  "%~dp0\..\@ionic\app-scripts\bin\ionic-app-scripts.js" %*
) ELSE (
  @SETLOCAL
  @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
  node --max_old_space_size=4096  "%~dp0\..\@ionic\app-scripts\bin\ionic-app-scripts.js" %*
)
```

If you are in Linux, you will need to add the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")

case `uname` in
    *CYGWIN*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
esac

if [ -x "$basedir/node" ]; then
  "$basedir/node --max_old_space_size=4096"  "$basedir/../@ionic/app-scripts/bin/ionic-app-scripts.js" "$@"
  ret=$?
else
  node --max_old_space_size=4096 "$basedir/../@ionic/app-scripts/bin/ionic-app-scripts.js" "$@"
  ret=$?
fi
exit $ret
```

You can also have a look into the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues/1036#issuecomment-310326176) where it states the previous.

If still changing the previous you are getting the out of memory issue, this is because you are limited by hardware in your device.